# Proof of ideal gas equation for container of arbitrary shape (kinetic theory)

Tags: thermodynamics

While deriving ideal gas equation - we take gas molecules to be contained in a cubical container (convenient shape) , but how do we derive it for a gas inside some arbitrarily shaped container ?

I think this has 2 answers:

1) Using maths - but it will be mostly impossible

2) There will be a theoretical proof (this is what I am interested into)

I could think of the ''theoretical'' proof - Check it whether its right:

Inside an arbitrarily shaped container we can imagine an imaginary cube shaped container (with imaginary boundaries, of course!)
and I think that the existence of those imaginary boundaries can be justified owing to the large number of intermolecular collisions, in sense -the place where we have assumed the imaginary boundaries of the cube-shaped container, right there the randomly moving molecules are colliding so fast and so much that, resultantly we can assume a wall existing right there.

And hence again do the same cubical container proof.

So is this right?

And some other ideas anybody?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law. Nowhere does the shape of the container enter into the derivation, as far as I can tell. The construction you are referring to is a general mathematical theorem.

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: I am assuming the OP is referring to this kind of proof: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases in which in fact it is usually assumed that the container is a cuboid.

Answer (score 1):

The hypothetical cubic box which is created effectively by collisions cannot be the solution at least Because sometimes the ideal gas is defined as the limit when there isn't any intermolecular interaction, even elastic collisions. (see for example [Sethna](http://pages.physics.cornell.edu/~sethna/StatMech/EntropyOrderParametersComplexity.pdf), p39)

But you can generalize the proof (in kenetic energy language) for the arbitrary shaped container by just considering a very small square area element on the wall and calculating how much momentum is transfered to this tiny element over a small $dt$ time. (You can find the details in many books, for example [Blundell](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/concepts-in-thermal-physics-9780199562107?cc=us&lang=en&), p56)

Comment: Can you please tell what's there in that book - Blindell pg 56 , as I don't have access to it.

Comment: Take a look at  this [notes](http://web.mit.edu/8.01t/www/materials/modules/chapter29.pdf) section 29.4.2, Although in Fig. 29.3 the container (the big box) is cubic, but it don't use that fact in the proof. you can repeat completely the same proof for an arbitrary shaped container; You choose a very small volume $\Delta V$ with very small rectangular base $A$ (the little box) on the wall of arbitrary shaped container and the rest of the proof is the same. If there is still an ambiguity, let me know to clarify that.

Comment: Excuse me for not writing the proof here, I am not very good with drawing figures in computer.

Comment: @seyed Is the net force that the fluid exerts on the container still zero for arbitrary shaped container?