# A question regarding the kinetic gas theory

Tags: thermodynamics

I am very confused by the following situation.

In the classic kinetic theory of gas, one calculates the pressure of an ideal gas in a $L*L*L$ space. Suppose we have a molecule start with a velocity $-v_x$, it hits the wall with rate $\frac{2L}{v_x}(*)$, so one calculates the average force $F = \frac{m{v_x}^{2}}{L}$, and one can derive a general law to calculate the pressure in an arbitrary-shaped container.

Now, what if the shape is a cylinder? In that case,$(*)$ changes based on different routes the molecule took.  How can we decide the rate the molecule hits the wall? Can we calculate the rate of collision for $x,y,z$ direction and average them? Can we just naively assume the situation is the same as a $L*L*L$ box?

I also found this link and the description in wikipedia but it didn't help:

[Proof of ideal gas equation for container of arbitrary shape (kinetic theory)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/269308/294688)

Comment: Here’s a resource you may find helpful http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/kinthe.html

Comment: The method you have met so far is really just a simple argument giving initial guidance on the relation between pressure and velocity distribution. A more careful calculation does not need to invoke the size or shape of the container, but you have to learn some slightly more advanced maths and physics to get it.

Comment: As @AndrewSteane has pointed out,  Simple one dimensional derivations for a cubic box give $mv_x^2 = PV$. Once it becomes a function of volume, shape is arbitrary.